# Using JQuery to update Array values at run time

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find a solution for this Table that I am cloning with JQuery. I am able to clone the table and update the ID and NAME properties to avoid html conflicts. I was able to get this to work during my original [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570298/cloned-select-fields-do-not-trigger-an-event/43570356#43570356) .  However, my goal is to actually provide choices that can then be duplicated by a user when ordering from a list of products.  I will then need to import these items for that one user into a database.  I have read that the best way to get these similar IDs into a database is to use an array, like ProductCode[0], etc...   I tried to apply this concept to my app, but once I added the array, the JQuery no longer updates the remaining fields when selected.  Is there a better way to use arrays that can then be cloned at run time, that can then be imported into a database with C# for processing?

The HTML Form that I am using to request a Selection:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%;">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate addsection"></span>
                        </div>
                        <select class="form-control" id="ProductCode[0]" name="ProductCode[0]" style="border-bottom-color:black!important;border-color:white;">
                            <option selected>Select Product</option>
                            <option value='292' data-description='APRIL Afternoon At the Greenhouse TICKET' data-price='35.00'>AAATG</option>
                            <option value='285' data-description='APRIL AFTERNOON AT THE GREENHOUSE Ticket EARLYBIRD SPECIAL' data-price='30.00'>AAATGearlybird</option>
                            <option value='30' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/2 Lb' data-price='4.25'>AB12LB</option>
                            <option value='31' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1/4 Lb' data-price='2.25'>AB14LB</option>
                            <option value='29' data-description='Organic Adzuki Beans 1 Lb' data-price='8.00'>AB1LB</option>
                            <option value='47' data-description='Organic Adzuki Seeds 1 Lb' data-price='5.00'>ABS1LB</option>
                            <option value='145' data-description='Alberto&#x27;s Lemon/Garlic Salad Dressing 16 Oz.' data-price='11.00'>Alberto&#x27;s Dressing</option>
                            <option value='241' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 4 oz.' data-price='2.00'>APRIL</option>
                            <option value='310' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 16 oz' data-price='7.75'>April16oz</option>
                            <option value='309' data-description='Organic Fenugreek Sprouted Beans 8 oz' data-price='4.00'>April8oz</option>
                            <option value='284' data-description='SeaVeggieSpecialAUGUST1Kelp/1Dulse/1TripleBlendPACKAGE of 3' data-price='11.50'>AUGUST</option>
                            <option value='271' data-description='DM Organic Tomato Basil Sauce CASE' data-price='36.00'>BB BasilS case</option>
                            <option value='273' data-description='DM Organic Tomato Chili Sauce CASE' data-price='36.00'>BB ChiliS case</option>
                            <option value='276' data-description='DM Organic Linguine Pasta CASE' data-price='36.00'>BB Lpasta case</option>
                            <option value='277' data-description='DM Organic Extra Virgin Olive Oil 500ML CASE' data-price='84.00'>BB OO 500ML</option>
                            <option value='278' data-description='DM Organic Extra Virgin Olive Oil 750ML CASE' data-price='132.00'>BB OO 750ML</option>
                            <option value='275' data-description='DM Organic Spaghetti Pasta CASE' data-price='36.00'>BB Spasta case</option>
                            <option value='274' data-description='DM Organic Tagliatelle Pasta CASE' data-price='36.00'>BB Tpasta case</option>
                            <option value='272' data-description='DM Organic Tomato Vegetable Sauce CASE' data-price='36.00'>BB VegS case</option>
                            <option value='117' data-description='Organic Mixed Beans 1 Lb' data-price='8.00'>BEEMB</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <td style="width:70%;"><input id="ProductDesc[0]" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;" name="ProductDesc[0]" type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input id="quantity[0]" class="form-control" style="width: 50px; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white; text-align: center;" name="quantity[0]" type="text" value="0" placeholder="1" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="ProductPrice[0]" class="form-control cost" style="width: 95px; text-align: center; border-bottom-color: black!important; border-color: white;" name="ProductPrice[0]" type="text" value="" placeholder="$0.00" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject remove"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The Script that I am using to update the remaining fields when the Product ID field is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('change', '#ProductCode[0]', function () {
        var data = "";
        data = $("#ProductCode[0] option:selected").data();
        $("#ProductDesc[0]").val(data.description);
        $("#quantity[0]").val(data.quant);
        $("#ProductPrice[0]").val(data.price);
        $("#DefaultUnitPrice[0]").val(data.price);
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#quantity[0]', function () {
        var quant = "";
        var data = "";
        data = $("#ProductCode[0] option:selected").data();
        quant = Number($("#quantity[0]").val());
        $("#ProductPrice[0]").val((data.price * quant).toFixed(2));
    });

});
```

Comment: i think the only thing why its wont work is cause the id has [] .. try somethink like this on ID's #ProductCode_0, only the input names are relevant for post data

Comment: First of all, `[` and `]` are not valid for an ID attribute, which consists of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name.  Secondly, you can use attribute selectors to make your event listeners more generic (e.g. `$(document).on('change', '[id^=quantity]', function () { ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [ and ] are not valid for an ID attribute, which consists of [letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods](https://w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name). Secondly, you can use attribute selectors to make your event listeners more generic (e.g. `$(document).on('change', '[id^=quantity]', function () { ...)` (`^=` is a [begins-with attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)). Lastly, you can use a second parameter for jquery objects as a means of giving a selector context.  This will reduce the number of times you have to have jQuery search the document.  All that comes down to the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('change', '[id^=ProductCode]', function () {
        var data = "";
        var curTable = $(this).closest('table');
        data = $("option:selected", curTable).data();
        $(this).val(data.description);
        $("[id^=quantity]", curTable).val(data.quant);
        $("[id^=ProductPrice]", curTable).val(data.price);
        $("[id^=DefaultUnitPrice]", curTable).val(data.price);
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '[id^=quantity]', function () {
        var quant = "";
        var data = "";
        var curTable = $(this).closest('table');
        data = $("option:selected", curTable).data();
        quant = Number($(this).val());
        $("[id^=ProductPrice]", curTable).val((data.price * quant).toFixed(2));
    });

});
```

However in the end, it might just be better to use classes instead of IDs

Comment: I had to make a correction to the first block; but, otherwise, it works nicely... Thank You!